# facebook way of synchronizing feeds/comments

Tags: ajax, facebook, comments, feed

I am developing a system much similar to the facebook.com . In this we have the feature that users (students) in our case can send status messages to his/her university fellows, the same way, we are using in the facebook. We can send comments against the feed also. I have done the  functionality of synchronizing feeds to all viewers of that feed. The same I want to do with the comments as soon as the new comment is added to the particular feed that feeds is updated with the latest comments without reloading the page. This is working fine for that particular user who send the comment but want to update the others as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: reproducing Facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript/jquery to check for the new feeds from database periodically, like 5 seconds.

If some new feeds/comments are saved in database, send back in response of the periodic request, and append to the respective feed, at bottom or at top.